# How To add automatic scrolling in slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add automatic scrolling time to my slider code but unable to do it can you please suggest me something to help me out with the code to make this slider slide automatic with a set interval of time.

```
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function () {

  var $slides = $('.con__slide').length,
      topAnimSpd = 650,
      textAnimSpd = 1000,
      nextSlideSpd = topAnimSpd + textAnimSpd,
      animating = true,
      animTime = 4000,
      curSlide = 1,
      nextSlide,
      scrolledUp;

  setTimeout(function () {
    animating = false;
  }, 2300);

  //navigation up function
  function navigateUp() {
    if (curSlide > 1) {
      scrolledUp = true;
      pagination(curSlide);
      curSlide--;
    }
  }

  //navigation down function
  function navigateDown() {
    if (curSlide < $slides) {
      scrolledUp = false;
      pagination(curSlide);
      curSlide++;
      console.log(curSlide);
    }
  }

  $(window).on('load', function () {
    $('.con__slide--1').addClass('active');
  });

  //pagination function
  function pagination(slide, target) {
    animating = true;
    // Check if pagination was triggered by scroll/keys/arrows or direct click. If scroll/keys/arrows then check if scrolling was up or down.
    if (target === undefined) {
      nextSlide = scrolledUp ? slide - 1 : slide + 1;
    } else {
      nextSlide = target;
    }
    ////////// Slides //////////
    $('.con__slide--' + slide).removeClass('active');

    setTimeout(function () {
      $('.con__slide--' + nextSlide).addClass('active');
    }, nextSlideSpd);

    ////////// Nav //////////
    $('.con__nav-item--' + slide).removeClass('nav-active');
    $('.con__nav-item--' + nextSlide).addClass('nav-active');

    setTimeout(function () {
      animating = false;
    }, animTime);
  }

  // Mouse wheel trigger
  $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
    var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    if (animating) return;
    // Mouse Up
    if (delta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
      navigateUp();
    } else {
      navigateDown();
    }
  });

  // Direct trigger
  $(document).on("click", ".con__nav-item:not(.nav-active)", function () {
    // Essential to convert target to a number with +, so curSlide would be a number
    var target = +$(this).attr('data-target');
    if (animating) return;
    pagination(curSlide, target);
    curSlide = target;
  });

  // Arrow trigger
  $(document).on('click', '.con__nav-scroll', function () {
    var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    if (animating) return;
    if (target === 'up') {
      navigateUp();
    } else {
      navigateDown();
    }
  });

  // Key trigger
  $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (animating) return;
    if (e.which === 38) {
      navigateUp();
    } else if (e.which === 40) {
      navigateDown();
    }
  });


  var topLink = $(".con__slide--4-top-h-link"),
      botLink = $(".con__slide--4-bot-h-link");
  $(".con__slide--4-top-h-link, .con__slide--4-bot-h-link").on({
    mouseenter: function mouseenter() {
      topLink.css('text-decoration', 'underline');
      botLink.css('text-decoration', 'underline');
    },
    mouseleave: function mouseleave() {
      topLink.css('text-decoration', 'none');
      botLink.css('text-decoration', 'none');
    }
  });
});
```

Hope you understand the above code if you have any query in it feel free to ask me and please help me out as soon as possible.

Comment: please post html also

Comment: @kaleemNalband here is the code with CSS and javascript included plz follow the link : https://jsfiddle.net/84ubpvx1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `setInterval` in your code.

```
setInterval(() => {
if (curSlide >= $slides){
    if (animating) return;
    pagination(4, 1);
    curSlide = 1;
} 
else
    navigateDown();
}, 10000);
```

Check [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84ubpvx1/1/).

Answer (score 0):

update below navigateDown code.
//navigation down function

```
  function navigateDown() {
    if (curSlide < $slides) {
      scrolledUp = false;
      pagination(curSlide);
      curSlide++;
      console.log(curSlide);
    }else{
    curSlide=1;
    pagination(4,1)
    }
  }
```

Add this below line

```
setInterval(navigateDown,7000);
```